# How to add a record to a table using parameters from differents View in ASP MVC and SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I want to add a record to the table 'Gamme' in my base.

The problem is that the parametres which used to fill out the table are taken from differents views.

This is the model **Gamme**:

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Gamme
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("Profile_Ga")]
        public string ID_Gamme { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("Poste")]
        public string ID_Poste { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int Nbr_Passage { get; set; }
        public string Last_Posts { get; set; }
        public string Next_Posts { get; set; }

        public virtual Poste Poste { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile_Ga Profile_Ga { get; set; }

    }
```

The **ID_Gamme** is taken from the view **Index** which the code is:

```
<div><%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedProfile_Ga", new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"))%> <input type="button" value="Configurer" id="btnShowGestion" /></div>
```

The other parameters are taken from the partial view **Gestion.ascx**:

```
 <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Poste Initial" id= "chkMain" onclick="test();"/>Poste Initial<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Poste Final" id= "chkFirst" onclick="test2();"/>Poste Final</div>


         <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Position)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <div><input type="button" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"  /></div>
```

I tried to create a function `Create` in my Controller but that's not given correct result:

```
public ActionResult Gestion(FlowViewModel model)
{

     model.YourGammeModel = new Gamme();
     return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Gamme gamme)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Gammes.Add(gamme);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Gestion");  
    }

    return View(gamme);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing exact code it is hard to know how you are loading partial page etc. The button won't do anything because there is no action associated with it. If you change it to a submit then it will fire the same controller as the main view with `HttpPost`.

Following on from there I think the issue is because your `HttpPost` action is not named correctly or accepting the correct parameter. In your example you should just use the same action name and ViewModel in the `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` so you probably want something like this:

Let's assume your **main** view is called Index.aspx:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(FlowViewModel model)
{
    // ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FlowViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {    
        db.Gammes.Add(model.YourGammeModel);
        db.SaveChanges();

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then on your PartialView (**Gestion.ascx**) you need to change your button to something like this: `<input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" />`

Finally, if you want your submit button to go somewhere other than the main view you need to change your `Html.BeginForm` code. So, let's say you have an action named `ExampleSave` on your controller **AnouarController** you would do this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ExampleSave", "Anouar"))
```